# SharePoint Calendar

Tags: calendar

Is there a sharepoint recurrence flag that you can set on the server to turn on and off recurrence? What we have done is changed the default install of sharepoint to disable recurrent in sharepoint calendars and now we want to turn them back on.

Comment: When you changed the "default install of SharePoint", how did you perform this?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a way to turn the recurrent event on or off.  If I am adding or editing a calendar it always appears on the page.  Is that where you are looking?

Comment: It was done manually during the set up. We edited the default settings so that there was not a posibility for someone to create a recurring event. We took out the option in the coding but now we do not know how to re add it.

Comment: I don't suppose you have the code the you used to disable it do you?  I can't seem to locate the property in the SDK.